# My text is being automatically highlighted

Tags: gedit

Wherever I am typing on Gedit, my text is being automatically highlighted.

For example when I type in anything the previous word is highlighted.

Is there a way to change this?

At line 22 it just starts highlighting randomly:

[image: s1]

Comment: I was typing in perl

Comment: Nope i turned it off tried to do a restart of the gedit... and for some reason it is still there.

Answer (score 1):

It's simply a syntax highlighting feature; it's triggered e.g. by the use of Perl's match, quoting, substitution and transliteration operators; in fact you'll notice that it happens only when typing `m`, `q`, `s` or `y`; it's probably there to highlight the fact that the operator has a syntax error.

So the only way to disable it would be to disable syntax highlighting altoghether.

[image: s1]

[image: s2]

Comment: I will try it out tomorrow when i am at my work desk

Comment: @Saifeki: after you've tried it out and it works, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: How to disable syntax highlighting altogether?